# ImageVIew with states for Lollipop version not working?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView and I want to make it clickable to press it and change the image. I used the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/back"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

on SrcCompat I put the above but nothing..

How can I do it with xml selector?

Comment: "for lollipop version not working"....and on lower API?

Comment: and  you need to add a drawable either for default state or for the false state...

Answer (score 0):

For selector not use enabled, just use only pressed or activated

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back" /> //for Default dont check state
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed" android:state_selected="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute in `ImageView` xml `android:clickable="true"`

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/your_drawable" />
```

Create drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back" /> //for Default dont check state
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed" android:state_selected="true" />
```